# Using pynput to get mouse coordinates

Tags: python, pynput

The program runs, but onclick I do not get a print statement of my x, and y.

I built a simple MoustInput class like so

```
from pynput import mouse
    
class MouseInput:
        def __init__(self):
            with mouse.Listener(on_click=self.on_click) as listener:
                listener.join()
    
        def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
            print('{0} at {1}'.format(
                'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
                (x, y)))
            if not pressed:
                # Stop listener
                return False
```

and then in app.py
I have something like this to call the class

```
from MouseInputs.mouse_input import MouseInput


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MouseInput()
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue.. It was a Mac related problem not allowing inputs to be detected..

I fixed this by allowing VSCode, and the terminal in accessibility in the Security & Privacy section of system preferences.